# Email in SPAM with Debian 8.2

Tags: debian, spam, g-suite, dkim

I have a problem (BIG PROBLEM) with SPAM.

All the emails my mail server (**Debian 8.2 and ispconfig latest stable**) send, end up in spam. I'm using **Google Apps**.

I did a test on `spamscorechecker.com` and the error message is:

- 0.1 DKIM_SIGNED Message has a DKIM or DK signature, not necessarily valid domain

My domain is ambrabaiocchi.it (with valid DKIM and SPF record) and more 3

For more info please check this: https://www.mail-tester.com/web-G3h54I
and this: http://www.lucavasini.it/output.rtf.

How can I solve the problem?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: From the mail-tester.com report, what I can see, your DKIM is ok. See the report again. The only problem found is `-1.985  PYZOR_CHECK  Listed in Pyzor (http://pyzor.sf.net/)`. May be you can try to resolve this. Have a look here: http://public.pyzor.org/whitelist/

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply. I have a problem with pyzor.. root@cloud1:~# ls
prova.eml
root@cloud1:~# pyzor info < prova.eml
root@cloud1:~#

Comment: Sorry, couldn't understand your comment. You can post any update to your original question. Are all your mails to any domain (gmail, yahoo, hotmail etc.) lands in spam? How have you tested it? Which client are you using? Have you tried with a different client?

Comment: Hello, yes I have tried with all client but same problem... all email sent to gmail, hotmail, yahoo go to spam.. Also all emails sent from CMS (prestashop, wordpress).. :( Thanks for your reply

Comment: Hello, I solved the problem with the help of google gapps
I added the ip of my server to the SPF record... like this: v=spf1 ip4:xx.xx.xx.xx include:_spf.google.com ~all Thank you for reply :)

Comment: You are welcome. You didn't mention you are using google apps. I have updated your question to add it and added an answer so that it may help others with similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to be missing spf record for Google Apps as described here: [Prevent your Google Mail from Getting Rejected as Spam](http://www.labnol.org/internet/authenticate-google-apps-email-with-spf/13877/)

One needs to add a spf record to the domain example.org to authorize google apps mail server to resolve the issue:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

> The entry `_spf.google.com` means that any server that is allowed to
>   send mail from the IP addresses of Google Apps mail servers is also
>   allowed to send mail from example.org. The ~all directive means that
>   email messages that are not sent from an approved server should still
>   be accepted but may be subjected to greater scrutiny.

Here is how to add it: [Configure SPF records to work with Google Apps](https://support.google.com/a/answer/178723?hl=en)